# Drop data from DataFrame because of insufficient values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to sum the total monthly amount by the code below,

```
month_sum = df.groupby(([df['Year'], df['Month']]))['amount'].agg(np.sum)
```

But I need to drop those data or change the sum result to NaN if they do not contain enough days' data(eg: only 10 groups of data for January).

I only know I can drop data by dp.drop(), which drop data according to column 
characteristics...And I cannot use it in this situation. Can anyone show me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this sample df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2017']*20, 'month': list('1')*12 + list('2')*8, 'amount': np.random.randint(0,50,20)})
```

You can sum by condition using lambda

```
df.groupby(['year', 'month']).amount.apply(lambda x: x.sum() if x.count() > 10 else np.nan).reset_index()
```

You get

```
    year    month   amount
0   2017    1       249.0
1   2017    2       NaN
```

Edit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': ['2017']*20, 'month': ['1']*12 + ['2']*8,\ 
'amount': np.random.randint(0,50,20),'other':np.random.randint(0,30,20)})

df.groupby(['year', 'month']).apply(lambda x: x['amount'].sum() if\ 
x['other'].sum() > 150 else np.nan).reset_index()
```

Comment: What if I want to use a condition rely on sum of other column?

    df=(raw_data.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['amount']
    .apply(lambda x: x.sum() if raw_data['othercolumn'].sum() >= n else np.nan).reset_index())

If othercolumn sum < n, It should return NaN but it turns to 0. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

You can always create a custom aggregation function.
For your example:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2017-01-01', '2017-02-05'))
df['amount'] = range(len(df))


def custom_sum(s):
    if len(s) > 10:
        return s.sum()
    else:
        return None

g = df.groupby([df.index.year, df.index.month])['amount'].agg(custom_sum)
print(g)
```

output:

```
2017  1    465.0
      2      NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed @vaishali's data set:

```
In [24]: df.groupby(['year', 'month']).amount \
           .agg(lambda x: x.sum() * 1 if x.count() > 10 else np.nan)
Out[24]:
year  month
2017  1        216.0
      2          NaN
Name: amount, dtype: float64
```